# How to sort MB, GB, TB values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL database table in which values are stored in a VARCHAR column like:

256 MB
2 GB
256 GB
512 GB
1 TB
2 TB

I tried following but its not giving correct results.

```
SELECT prod_srch_ssd FROM products WHERE prod_srch_ssd <> '' AND prod_type = 'laptop' AND prod_status = 'active' GROUP BY prod_srch_ssd ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN prod_srch_ssd LIKE '%TB' THEN power(1024, 4) * substr(prod_srch_ssd, 1, LENGTH(prod_srch_ssd) - 2)
    WHEN prod_srch_ssd LIKE '%GB' THEN power(1024, 3) * substr(prod_srch_ssd, 1, LENGTH(prod_srch_ssd) - 2)
    WHEN prod_srch_ssd LIKE '%MB' THEN power(1024, 2) * substr(prod_srch_ssd, 1, LENGTH(prod_srch_ssd) - 2)
    WHEN prod_srch_ssd LIKE '%KB' THEN power(1024, 1) * substr(prod_srch_ssd, 1, LENGTH(prod_srch_ssd) - 2)
    WHEN prod_srch_ssd LIKE '%B'  THEN substr(prod_srch_ssd, 1, LENGTH(prod_srch_ssd) - 1)
END DESC
```

How to sort these so that it shows in following order TB, GB, MB ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using WRONG database type for your data. Your 'workaround' will result in terribly unperformant queries.

Comment: It would be better to store the *data* as numerical data, all using the same scale, and leave conversion to `MB`, `GB`, etc, properly to your *presentation* layer.